# SQL transaction commit and error handle

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

My code is as following:

```
create my sp 
as 
    declare cursor 
    open cursor

    fetch next from 
    begin try
       begin transaction tran1
         exec sp_1.... 
       commit transaction tran1

       select * from table

       begin transaction tran2
           exec sp_2.... 
       commit transaction tran2
    end

    fetch next from cursor
end try

begin catch

SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
ROLLBACK TRAN;

fetch next from cursor
end catch
close cursor
deallocate cursor
```

I need this code to :

1. contain two transactions and rollback when error happened
2. when the stored procedure gets killed, the transaction will still rollback

I think that the catch part may not right, because there are two transaction and needs to be specific.

Comment: This should be okay as if 1st transaction fails due to an error it would not go to the next transaction  but rather to the error itself. Hence you don't have to worry about an error occurring and not being captured in  2nd transaction. Then if the 1st transaction is successful and 2nd transaction fails then the error would also get captured. One thing I don't see here is the begin try.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add the begin try on my answer, so the error handling will catch both of the transaction?

Comment: Yes. Because the if the 1st fails it will not go to second but to the error handling. So you don't have to worry about not capturing the 2nd transaction. If it's the 2nd one that fails when 1st is successful then you don't have to worry about the first 1.